# current location is not accurate using getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Unable to get accurate location its giving location but its different from my current location.

This is the url where i implemented
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          
          // this.showPosition(position);
              console.log("swd",position.coords)

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says on that page, `Note: Geolocation is most accurate for devices with GPS, like smartphones.`, so if you're not on a device with GPS, it probably is going based on your IP address, which isn't necessarily the most accurate if you're on a corporate/university network or behind any sort of proxy

Comment: i have my laptop can it work on laptop with wifi for internet connection

Comment: The answer applies to any device